# Exception when opening Samsung S Planner via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to open the installed calendar app so that the user can enter a new event. I use the following intent which works fine on Nexus and many other devices.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```

The only problem so far are Samsung devices with the S Planner calendar app installed. When the intent is executed the following exception is show in LogCat and the S Planner app crashes hard (with system error dialog).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.event.EditEventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.calendar.CalendarEventModel.(CalendarEventModel.java:406)
    at com.android.calendar.event.EditEventFragment.onAttach(EditEventFragment.java:548)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:787)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
    ... 11 more
```

While trying to track down what is going on in the `CalendarEventModel` I didn't find any clues to it in the [publicly available sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.2_r1/com/android/calendar/CalendarEventModel.java#CalendarEventModel.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.content.Intent%29).

Does anybody have an idea how to properly start the S Planner to create a new event?

Comment: [Calendar Provider guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) has some examples for [adding new events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event), [updating events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#update-event), [deleting events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#delete-event)… I hope it would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I helped to get on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I've created this utility class for creating calendar events, hope you find it usefull:

```
public class CalendarOrganizer {
    private final static int ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID = 14;
    /**
     * Creates a calendar intent going from startTime to endTime
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @param context
     * @return true if the intent can be handled and was started, 
     * false if the intent can't be handled
     */
    public static boolean createEvent(long startTime, long endTime, String title, String description, 
            String location, boolean isAllDay, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID) {
            // all SDK below ice cream sandwich
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
            intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", location);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", isAllDay);

//          intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        } else {
            // ice cream sandwich and above
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
            intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
            intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY , isAllDay);
            intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);

//          intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10") 
        }
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the various replies. I have figured it out. The S Planner requires to have a start and end date set. Otherwise it crashes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getMillis())
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getMillis());
```